# How To clear pending messages from GCM?

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have an cordova App , when user login new "app registrationId" is sent to server and is saved in database for further use (when app user receive a message from someone else ) , however when user logout i want to clear all pending message in gcm , so that if another user login  he doesn't receive Previous user notifications.

is there any way to do this in GCM ? or my scenario is totally wrong !?

thanks.

Comment: You should send userID in GCM payload and check it at client side, if userID received in GCM is for current login user then show it's notification otherwise ignore it.

Comment: Hi @Arash were you able to try out the approach in my answer? Was it good? If so, please accept it as the correct answer so that your post will properly tagged. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A registration token corresponds to a single app instance (*tied to the device*) and not to a single user specifically.

I've also searched around about this topic before and the usual solution is for you to have a user identifier included in your payload, let's say a `userid`. Then in your client app, you must check if the `userid` matches the one who is currently logged-in. If true, show the notification, else, disregard the message.

With this, if a different user is logged-in and a push was sent to that specific registration token, your app will handle it and will not show any details not for the corresponding user.

However, this means that only if the original user is logged-in will your app be showing a notification.

Anyways, it's still a valid workaround for the behavior you're aiming for. Hope that makes sense. Cheers!

Comment: so the notification will be shown in android status bar , but when user click the app validater userId and take appropriate action ! right ?

Comment: @Arash Yes. Depending on the type of payload you are using, I think you should use `data` payload so that your client app will handle it in `onMessageReceived` then if the `userId` doesn't match, don't show any notifications.

Comment: i havent yet , i am struggeling to handle cordova push when the app is in background , i will try your answer when i handle that . thanks .

Comment: I see. Good luck then. Let me know how it goes. Cheers!